# Creating sessions while user signs up in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

HI ,

i have some doubts on sign up feature in rails application (2.3.10)

in my views/users/new.html.erb

```
<div id="signup_form" style="display:none;" class="login-drpdwn ">
  <% form_for :user, :url => users_path do |f| -%>
    <%= error_messages_for 'user' %><br/>
    <div>
      <p> Enter your  name </p>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "text_box" %>
      <p> Enter your login name </p>
      <%= f.text_field :login, :class => "text_box" %>
      <p> Email ID</p>
      <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "text_box" %>
      <p> Password</p>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "text_box" %>
      <p> Confirm your password</p>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "text_box" %>
      <div class="textalign_right">
        <input type="submit"  value="Submit"  class="submit_button rounded_corner"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In my Users controller

```
before_filter :login_required, :except => [:new, :create, :forgot, :reset, :process_forgot_password, :activate]

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])     
  if @user.save
    redirect_to "/blogs/home",:notice => "signed up"
  else
    redirect_to "new"
  end
end
```

In my User model

```
before_save :encrypt_password
attr_protected :id, :password_salt
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

def self.authenticate(email, password)
  user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
  user
  else
    nil
  end
end

def encrypt_password
  if password.present?
    self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
  end
end
```

In my sessions controller - create method

```
def create
  @current_user = User.find_by_login(params[:login].downcase)
  if @current_user.blank? || params[:password] !=  @current_user.password_hash
    @current_user = nil
    render :action => "new"
  else
    session[:user_id] = @current_user.id
    session[:close_time] = 1800.seconds.from_now

    if @current_user.last_login.nil?
      @login = LastLogin.new
      @login.user_id = @current_user.id
      @login.login_at = Time.now
      @login.save
    else
      @login = @current_user.last_login
      @login.last_at = @login.login_at
      @login.login_at = Time.now
      @login.login_count += 1
      @login.save
    end

    if session[:return_to]
      redirect_to session[:return_to], :protocol => USE_PROTOCOL
      session[:return_to] = nil
    else
    end
  end
end
```

when i submit the sign up page the user is getting created but not the session 
so its not directing to the blogs /home page as it has before_filter :login_required there in blogs controller..

how to resolve this
My code is not having include Authenticated system line

Answer (score 5):

```
    session[:id] = @current_user.id
```

Comment: where should i insert the line ?/

Comment: Modify the 7th line down in your Create method. So generally speaking, use the pre-defined session[:id] instead of session[:user_id]